# How to use google places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm new to android programming and I want to ask how to get started with google places API. I've already searched so much on https://developers.google.com/places/training/basic-place-search and I'm not able to get a clear and organised result. Please help.

Comment: Well, what have you already tried? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ here the google developers explain how to use and where to get the Api Key. Here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html you'll get a full tutorial how to work with coordinates and display a position n your mapview. So i hope this will help you to get started.

Answer (score 3):

To use the Places API from a Java/Android application, you'll need to do the following:

1. Get a Places API key from Google.
2. Make HTTP requests to the API, using something like Apache's `HttpClient` class that are included in the Android SDK. JSON-formatted data will be easier to work with than XML.
3. Take the response string, parse it using the `JSONObject` class, and then drill down into these `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` objects to get at the data that you want.

A Google search for "google places api android" turns up a handful of tutorials, such as this one: http://karnshah8890.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-places-api-tutorial.html

You may also be interested in a library like [this third-party offering on GitHub](https://github.com/gmarz/android-google-places), which wraps the HTTP API calls into a more friendly object-oriented interface.